# Set DevExpress Grid Tableview Editable property and determine its parent via RTTI

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have a project with multiple TcxGrids on. The class hierarchy structure of the grids in my project are as follows:

TForm->TPanel->TcxPageControl->TcxTabSheet(subclassed)->TcxGrid->TcxGridLevel->TcxGridDBBandedTableView

In my subclassed TcxTabSheet I have added a new property "ReadOnly" that when set loops over the tabsheets controls and sets them to enabled/disabled respectively.

When a TcxGrid controls enabled property is set to true, the user can no longer interact with the grid at all (including navigating).

It seems I need to set the OptionsData.Editing property on the TcxGridDBBandedTableView to achieve a readonly but still navigable grid control.

Simple enough until you factor in that I want to do this in a loose coupled manner which I think leaves me the option of RTTI.

I have written the following code that loops over the forms controls (looping over the tabs controls or components doesn't give me access to the TcxGridDBBandedTableView). Once the control is found I can set its editing property via RTTI. I just don't seem to able to determine if that TcxGridDBBandedTableView  belongs to the TabSheet it sits on.

```
var
  compIdx: Integer;
begin
  for compIdx := 0 to Pred(ComponentCount) do
    if (Components[compIdx].ClassNameIs('TcxGridDBBandedTableView')) then
      SetOrdProp(GetObjectProp(Components[compIdx], 'OptionsData'), 'Editing', Ord(not FReadOnly));
end;
```

TL;DR
How can I determine what pagectrl tab a cxgrid is on and set its TableView.OptionsData.Editable property without adding any devexpress units to the uses clause of the unit.

Comment: the porperty Control which would be necessary to get the cxGrid seems not to be reachable via RTTI.

Comment: What about adding an event for your Readonly property, which could be used in the template of your projects using cxGrid for iterating over contained cxgrids/views.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the components owned by the form. I think that's the wrong approach. You should be looking at the parent/child relationship rather than ownership. Not least because it's perfectly possible for a form to contain controls that it does not own. So, your approach can fail to find controls, particularly dynamically created controls.

So, if you have a tabsheet (or indeed any windowed control), you can iterate over its children like this:

```
for i := 0 to TabSheet.ControlCount-1 do
  DoSomething(TabSheet.Controls[i]);
```

If your target grid control is a direct descendent of the tabsheet then this will be enough. If it is more than one level deep in the hierarchy then you will need a recursive solution. I will leave that recursive solution as an exercise for you.

Suppose that you have a control and want to find the tabsheet that it sits inside, then you need to walk up the parent chain. Like this:

```
function GetParentOfClass(Control: TControl; AClass: TWinControlClass): TWinControl;
var
  Control: TWinControl;
begin
  while Assigned(Control) and not (Control is AClass) do
    Control := Control.Parent;
  Result := TWinControl(Control);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this down but sadly this doesn't help solve my issue as a TcxGridDBBandedTableView does not descend from a TWinControl and therefore does not have the parent property yet I can see from the Delphi 2007 Structure viewer that the view is indeed parented by the TcxGrid control - I just wish I could find out how it can work it out.

Comment: You have to work out how to get back to the grid control. Then my answer is what you need.

Comment: Your comment is essentially a TL;DR of my question. It's what I'd love to have the answer to as there are no published properties in the TcxGridDBBandedTableView that hint at that parentage.

Comment: @Paul: FWIW, you can get from View to Grid via Site.Container - see [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q21159)

Comment: OK, looks like that completes the puzzle

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Uli. I don't know how I can accept your comment as the answer though.

Comment: "TL;DR How can I determine what pagectrl tab a cxgrid is on"